# Cannot use initialState="stopped" in my flow attribute

Tags: mule, mule-flow

I try to config my Mule flow

`<flow name="..." initialState="stopped">`

I have got "Attribute initialState is not defined as a valid property of flow".

What is wrong? Could clarify?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please mention the Mule Version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old Mule version, perhaps? This property is not available in some older versions.

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6025

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a bug in MuleStudio. You might find that the error displays on studio but it will still run without issues, tested it myself.